# Add 100 to decimals in Multiple TXT files

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I am confused over this, so need some help. I have multiple txt files in one folder. And there's some content in those text files. Now there is one text `"moveLimit":30,` (comma is after the decimal). So how do I add `100` to all the moves decimal in multiple files and save them. The moves is not `30`, it's random number in every text files. And they all are between 10-999.

[sample](https://pastebin.com/4siq4xC9)

```
{"gameModeName":"Classic moves","moveLimit":106,"numberOfColours":6,"portals":[],"protocolVersion":"0.3","randomConfig":{"mode":"Seed Pool","modeModifier":"Tutorial Only","overrideAbTest":true,"seedPool":[547787]},"randomSeed":1088126,"scoreTargets":[300,400,500],"tileMap":[["000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000"],["000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000"],["002005","002005","002005","002005","002005","002005","002005","002005","000"],["002","002","002","002","002","002","002","002","000"],["002","002","002","002","002","002","002","002","000"],["002","002","002","002","002","002","002","002","000"],["002","002","002","002","002","002","002","002","000"],["000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000"],["000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000","000"]]}
```

Comment: post a testable file's content (we need to see whether `"moves":30,` is a part of the line or stands as a separate line)

Comment: It's in a single line, and doesn't stand therefore as a separate line.

Comment: A full example would still be good.

Comment: Uploading to pastebin

Comment: Instead of uploading to pastebin, please put a sample here in the question. AND a sample of the corresponding expected output Just 4 or 5 lines will be sufficient. (Paste it here, select the lines, use `{}` on the formatting bar to mark it as code.) A question should ideally be complete in itself.

Comment: Also specify whether there could be multiple entries `"moves":<number>,` on the same line

Comment: The reason we'd like to see a full example is that if the files are JSON files (or in some other structured text format), it changes the tools that we use for solving the issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you would say at the very start that your `txt` files are actually JSON files (as your sample just looks like) - it would have changed everything and prevent most of the questions/comments.

Use a proper JSON tools like `jq` as this would be the right way:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    if grep -q '"moveLimit":[0-9]*,' "$f"; then
        jq -c '.moveLimit |= . + 100' "$f" > tmp_f && mv tmp_f "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @PJ547 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU or FreeBSD system, you could try something like:

```
grep  -rl --null '"moveLimit":[0-9]' . |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e 's/"moveLimit":\K\d+/$& + 100/ge'
```

- `grep` `r`ecursively `l`ists the files in the current directory (`.`) that contain `"moveLimit":` followed by a decimal digit (`null`-delimited for `xargs -0`)
- `xargs -r0` passes that list of files to `perl`
- `perl` edits the files `i`n-place and replaces sequences of digits (`\d+` that follow `"moveLimit":` with the same number (`$&`) plus 100.